# SQL Query - Ignore null values unless statement

Tags: sql

I need help with an SQL Query. I am querying my active directory and I need to ignore all objects who have their manager field set to null UNLESS the object has a certain name. I am not quite sure how to perform the UNLESS statement that I need. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT     distinguishedName AS UniqueId,
           department,
           Title, 
           Manager AS ManagerId,
           displayName AS Name, 
           mail AS Email,
           thumbnailphoto AS photo
 FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'SELECT mail,
                             CN,
                             distinguishedName,
                             Manager, 
                             displayName, 
                             Title,
                             department,
                             thumbnailphoto FROM                 
                             ''LDAP://internal.mesacounty.us'
                                  'WHERE objectCategory=''Person'' AND   
                                   objectClass = ''User''') AS derivedtbl_1
     WHERE     (Manager IS NOT NULL ***UNLESS DisplayName = ''WHATEVER NAME I CHOOSE'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `UNLESS` with `OR` should do it.

Comment: Worked like a charm I must have been over thinking it lol thanks!